# How to recursively replace dictionary values with a matching key?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to take a dictionary and find all of the keys that match `key` and replace their value with `replace_value`. The dictionaries can in theory be infinitely deep, so it must be done recursively.

My current solution replaces values correctly, but raises an exception saying "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" (not to mention the fact that it's poor use of recursion with no return values).

```
def replace_item(obj, key, replace_value):
    """
    Replaces the dictionary value of key with replace_value in the obj dictionary.
    """
    if key in obj:
        obj[key] = replace_value
    
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            item = replace_item(v, key, replace_value)

            if item is not None:
                item = replace_value

     return obj
```

An example of an operation it would perform would be the following:

**Original Dictionary**

```
person_dict = {
    "name": "Alex",
    "sex": "M",
    "title": "Engineer",
    "misc": {
        "mailbox": "3A",
        "work_type": "remote"
    }
}
```

Then I'd make a call to `replace_item(person_dict, "work_type", "office")`, which I'd preferably like to change over to returning the updated dictionary (`person_dict = replace_item(person_dict, "work_type", "office")`).

**Replaced Value Dictionary**

```
person_dict = {
    "name": "Alex",
    "sex": "M",
    "title": "Engineer"
    "misc": {
        "mailbox": "3A",
        "work_type": "office"
    }
}
```

How can I go about fixing my recursion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have some strange behavior where you are expecting a `return` but you don't have one.  Also your description implies it should replace nested keys, but your code you will miss when a dictionary at the top level does not have the key but at a lower level does.  I believe the below code accomplishes what you described:

```
def replace_item(obj, key, replace_value):
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            obj[k] = replace_item(v, key, replace_value)
    if key in obj:
        obj[key] = replace_value
    return obj
```

**EDIT**: As @dashiell suggested, moving the top level reassignment after the recursive search/replace avoids the infinite recursion trap of having `key` exist in the `replace_value`.

Comment: I think you want to have `obj[k] = replace....` rather than `obj[key][k] = repla....` otherwise if `replace_value` is a dict containing the key `key`, you get an infinite loop that will always result in a recursion depth exception.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to to put the replacement below the recursion. For example, someone could get a max recursion depth error by setting `key=some_key,replace_value={some_key:some_value}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a functional-style take:

```
def replace(obj, key, val):
    return {k: replace(val if k == key else v, key, val) 
        for k,v in obj.items()} if isinstance(obj, dict) else obj
```

It's not efficient in Python (since all values/subdicts are re-created), but demonstrates how to solve your problem without side-effects and without mutating objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that removes the need for recursion (though perhaps json uses recursion on its own converting a dict to a string and back):

```
import json
import re

def replace_item(obj, key_to_replace, replace_value):
    pattern = re.compile(f'"{key_to_replace}":[^,]+')

    config_str = json.dumps(obj)

    assert pattern.search(config_str)
    config_str = re.sub(pattern, f'\"{key_to_replace}\": {replace_value}', config_str)

    return json.loads(config_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace_item(obj, key, replace_value):
    """
    Replaces the dictionary value of key with replace_value in the obj dictionary.
    """
    if key in obj:
        obj[key] = replace_value

    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            replace_item(v, key, replace_value)
```

I think this is enough.. no need of extra variables,
and in most of the systems, default recursion depth is around 1000, you can change it https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Answer (score 1):

This you can use when there is list of dict of list...

```
def replace_item(obj, key_to_replace, replace_value):
    if type(obj)==list:
        newObj=[]
        for objx in obj:
            objx=replace_item(objx, key_to_replace, replace_value)
            newObj.append(objx)
        return newObj
    obj=dict((replace_value if key==key_to_replace else key, value) for (key, value) in obj.items())
    for k in obj.keys():
        if type(obj[k]) in [dict,list]:
            obj[k]=replace_item(obj[k], key_to_replace, replace_value)
    return obj
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: Please use code formatting for better readability